# Detect which Lock() causes program to hang?

Tags: go

In my go program, the execution is hung up because it is waiting for Lock(). Are there tools in go which I can use to find the exact line where it is getting deadlocked?

Comment: You don't need a tool, a stack trace will show the status of all goroutines.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a stack trace using [pprof](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/).

If you follow the example code in the package the url http://localhost:6060/debug/pprof/goroutine?debug=1 will give you a stack trace of every running goroutine.